# Highcharts: Not plotting correctly with Y-Axis label formatter

Tags: highcharts

When I use a Y-Axis label formatter, sometimes the points don't plot correctly. The point "6.8" is plotting just above the 6.8 line. Also, the Y-Axis ticks are not equal intervals (7.8, 7.5, 7.3, 7.0, 6.8, 6.5). Removing the label formatter clears up the issue. Anyone know a work-around so I can keep the label formatter?

With label formatter: http://jsfiddle.net/3TKDt/1/

Without label formatter: http://jsfiddle.net/3TKDt/2/

Label formatter:

```
yAxis: 
{
  labels: {
    formatter: function () {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you after with the `numberFormat` function?  With your 6.8 point, highcharts is passing in a tick at 6.75 and you are returning the label "6.8".  The tick is still at 6.75, you are just adjusting the label.

Comment: That's worth adding as an answer

Comment: Makes sense now. I suppose doing a numberFormat on the Y-Axis labels isn't good practice. The product owner wanted all numbers shown to have 1 decimal point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a numberFormat function on the Y-Axis labels wasn't a good idea. It was rounding the tick marks and representing the intervals incorrectly.  I removed the label formatter.